# Python machine learning brute force

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a dataset from which I try to predict one value. I tried linear regression, but it doesn't work.

Is there an algorithm in Python which will compute a good statistical model (neural network) in every case? What I am looking for is the brute force algorithm for machine learning. The only thing I care about is how good the prediction is.

Comment: This question is way too broad,  how does you dataset look ? what are your target variables, do you have any prior knowledge on the constraints? what is your loss function ?

Comment: This is this dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/c/bike-sharing-demand/data?train.csv

Comment: I have voted to close this as too broad, but I wonder whether it is salvaged in some ways by Zach's answer. I also wonder if we have a duplicate question somewhere where someone asks for a technique that would work on any dataset, and there was a similar response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, no.  There's a "no free lunch theorem" in machine learning that there's no a-priori distinction in machine learning algorithms.

The best technique is usually to try a wide diversity of algorithms on your dataset, and pick the one that seems to give the best out-of-sample error.

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) contains great functions for doing this.  I suggest you try a [random forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests) first.  Those often give pretty good results on real-world, tabular data.

Comment: You're probably right. I'm sad you are right, but I have to admit it. Thanks !

Comment: (+1) Perhaps worth emphasizing that the no free lunch theorem applies to your "best technique" too.

Comment: Random Forest improved my results a lot !

Comment: @Scortchi Totally correct!  It's a tricky problem.

Comment: @Moebius Glad to hear that!